# Magento2 developer mode and fatal errors

Tags: magento2, fatal-error, apache, developer-mode

Magento2 is set in developer mode (`deploy:mode:set developer` and checked env.php file) but it is showing a `HTTP ERROR 500 page isn't working` screen.

Only if I add this to the index:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I receive the error:

```
Fatal error: Class '...\Framework\App\Action\Action' not found in /data/web/public/app/code/.../Controller/Index/Index.php on line 15
```

Is something missing in my apache configuration? I'm using hypernode vagrant box for magento2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP do not have API to catch FATAL Errors (especially in PHP < 7) it's why you need to enable display error by self

Comment: ah ok, didn't know that